# Multiple precision elementary functions implementation

Tags: c++, mpfr

I'm trying to find an implementation of a multiple precision version of the sin functions. I'm trying to read through the mpfr library (the C/C++ source code) but I can't find any code related to the actual implementation.

What I basically want to know is how the argument reduction is performed in such case (multiple precision), It's probably possible that a huge LUT is stored to represent the inverse of `pi`, that would allow to handle all possible cases (with cases I mean the mantissa size).

Could you point me out what specific source to look at? The code is quite complicated to read through.

Answer (score 1):

The range reduction is not implemented with a huge LUT: this is not possible because the exponent range is too large. What is done is just to compute pi with sufficient accuracy; the value of pi is cached for the next calls to the trigonometric functions, and pi is recomputed each time more accuracy is needed.

You can get information by looking at the source of MPFR and/or by building `algorithms.pdf` from the `doc` directory with LaTeX. But this document may not be always up-to-date and some information may be missing.

Comment: What do you mean by sufficient accuracy? Is it computed each time I want to evaluate a trig function?

Comment: @user8469759 The function implementation calls `mpfr_const_pi` on a variable that has some precision (determined dynamically). For instance, if the variable has a precision of 500 bits and the cached value of pi has a precision of 600 bits, then pi will *not* be recomputed; but if the cached value of pi has a precision of 400 bits, the function `mpfr_const_pi` will recompute pi to get at least 500 bits of precision.

Comment: Why is `pi` necessary in place of it's inverse (`1/pi`)?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, an improvement may be possible with 1/pi instead of pi. But one would need the equivalent to `mpfr_remainder` for the multiplication instead of division. Note however that the constant pi may be used for other things, thus may be more interesting than 1/pi.